# What is Gitlab's instance domain?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to test to see if my SSH key was added correctly by following the instructions which are found halfway down the page [here](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#testing-that-everything-is-set-up-correctly).

> To test whether your SSH key was added correctly, run the following
>   command in your terminal (replacing gitlab.com with your GitLab's
>   instance domain):

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

However, I have no idea what my "Gitlab's instance domain" is referring to. I have searched other online but I cannot find anything relevant.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you're using Gitlab on gitlab.com then the domain is gitlab.com, so you should run  `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`

Answer (score 7):

Gitlab can be installed locally so Gitlab instance is what is being run locally. E.g., if one runs Gitlab instance at `gitlab.example.net` the domain is `gitlab.example.net`, and the `ssh` command is `ssh -T git@gitlab.example.net`.

For Gitlab at `gitlab.com` the command is `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a real definition but one section below in [that same page](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README#testing-that-everything-is-set-up-correctly) you can find the example of the content of a file ~/.ssh/config

```
# GitLab.com
    Host gitlab.com
    Preferredauthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_com_rsa

# Private GitLab instance
    Host gitlab.company.com
    Preferredauthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/example_com_rsa
```

which links the notion of 'instance' to the notions of 'private' and 'company'. Not a foolproof hint, but at least it introduces something clearly distinct from GitLab.com proper.

**Basically, if you are a vanilla user, it will be just fine to type** `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`.

That instruction is a test before starting the dance. Worked for me also down the line, when I cloned the repository I was interested in with a `git clone git@gitlab.com:<myreponame>.git`.

Answer (score 3):

If your git (or gitlab) repo is something like `https://a.b.com/abc/abcd` then
first, you clone using ssh (after adding your public ssh key) to repo, and then test using `ssh -T git@a.b.com`. That's it!!